# REST: Get query only changeable objects

Tags: rest, api-design

I'm having a bunch of apis which return several types of data.
All users can query all data by using a GET rest api.

A few users can also change data. What is a common approach when designing REST API, to query only the data that can be changed by the current user but still allow the api to return all data (for display mode).

To explain it further:

The software manages projects. All projects are accessible for all users (also anonymous) via an api (let's call it GET api/projects).
A user has the ability to see a list of all projects he is involved in and which he can edit. 
The api should return exactly the same data but limited to the projects he is involed in.

Should I create an additonal parameter, or maybe pass an http header, or what else?

Comment: Hi - do you return properties along with your data fields that can contain an 'editable' (Boolean) field? If that's the case, assuming that you're able to identify the user and their respective role/privilege via you authorization mechanism, you can return 'editable' set to true or false, for each data field.

Comment: I've added some further explaination. Adding editable is not an option, because the total volume of objects compared to his own objects is to low (like 1/100000). That would mean that 100000 objects would be fetched to find one which is editable.

Comment: Thank you for providing more info. I meant if you do have a field that can identify an editable project (e.g. 'editable'), then you can structure your GET like 'api/projects?editable=true' to only return editable projects for that given user. If this is a system only API, and not exposed to others, you can also pass the 'userId' along with the 'editable' parameter for filtering.

Answer (score 0):

There's no one-size-fits-all answer to this, so I will give you one recommendation that works for some people.

I don't really like creating resources that have 'complex access control'. Instead, I would prefer to create distinct resources for different access levels.

If you want to return limit results for people that have partial access, it might be better to create new resources that reflect this.

I think this might also help a bit thinking about the abstract role of a person who is not allowed to do everything. The abstraction probably doesn't exist per-property, but it exists somewhere as a business rule.